# How to integrate facebook plugin page into blogger?

Tags: javascript, facebook, widget, blogger, facebook-page

I'm trying to integrate facebook plugin page into blogger ?
I am following the steps in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/#

My facebook page is https://www.facebook.com/YourWebsiteTraffic

First remark, there is no preview of the plugin (this normally should appear)
[image: https://www.facebook.com/YourWebsiteTraffic]

I had integrated the first code after the  tag of blogger theme:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.0&appId=1639125536140367&autoLogAppEvents=1';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

[image]

However, After entering the second part below in a new widget:

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/YourWebsiteTraffic/" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="300" data-height="300" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="false" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"></div>
```

[image]
I get this new code after the body tag:
[image]

I'm totally lost now, can somebody please help. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

To solve it: go to the page settings and chane page visibility to Published :)
[image]